# Automatic Hashtags when you share on twitter

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improvements to the prefilled content of the Tweet this button](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87003/improvements-to-the-prefilled-content-of-the-tweet-this-button)

Lets say I'm on a question I've just asked and click the [tweet link](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=How%20do%20I%20pick%20a%20VPN%20provider?&url=https://security.stackexchange.com/q/3973/488). That's good, but we can do better. Instead of `How do I pick a VPN provider? http://t.co/yAk5ZLQ` we could have `How do I pick a #VPN provider? http://t.co/yAk5ZLQ #Security #StackExchange`.

Obviously this isn't a canned solution, but if you want to improve the usefulness of social media tools we've already using, this looks like a good option to explore.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget you're on Twitter. You need to make room for the subject's title. So adding hashtags may not be very clever.

I prefer to have a full title rather than hashtags.

Comment: Absolutely. I'm not saying append a bunch of things and forget the title, but fit them in if we can.

Comment: Hum then maybe. Eventually if the title has words that are also tags, maybe they can be turn to #tag.